# Do we omit the personal pronoun when joining two sentences using conjunction "and"?

Tags: conjunctions, ellipsis

Which is the correct way to join the sentences below using conjunction "and"? Do we need to use personal pronoun "she" as per (2) or can it be omitted as per (1)?

> My mother went shopping. My mother bought me a doll.

1. > My mother went shopping and bought me a doll.
2. > My mother went shopping and she bought me a doll.

Comment: Both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

To my limited perception, the two sentences have slightly different meanings.  When the personal pronoun is used

> My mother went shopping and *she* bought me a doll.

the connection between going shopping and buying a doll is a *coincidental*.  If you omit the pronoun

> My mother went shopping and bought me a doll.

it says (to my ear, anyway) that buying a doll was in part *the aim* of mother's going shopping.